# IBM Websphere - exception in wsadmin script for AutoDeployment

Tags: websphere, jython, web-deployment, ear, wsadmin

I'm trying to write a simple Jython script to AutoDeploy a web application on the IBM Websphere Application Server. However, I'm a novice in Python, so I can't uderstand, why do I become the following Error:

```
WASX7209I: Connected to process "dmgr" on node was7CellManager01 using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: DeploymentManager
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "deploy_test.py"; exception information: com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: exception from Jython:
Traceback (innermost last):
File "<string>", line 14, in ?
TypeError: sequence subscript must be integer or slice
```

My script:

```
appname='name'
source='app.ear'
nodeName='was7Node01'
cell='was7Cell01'
server='server1'
contextRoot='/deploymenttest'

    # 1. node
    # 2. cell
    # 3. server
    # 4. Application Name
    # 5. ContextRoot
    # 5. JNDI target name 
attrs = [
         '-node ', nodeName,
         ' -cell ', cell,
         ' -server ', server,
         ' -appname ', appname,
         ' -CtxRootForWebMod ', contextRoot,
         ' -MapResRefToEJB ', [
                               [ 
                                 appname,"",
                                 source+',WEB-INF/web.xml',
                                 'jdbc/appdb','javax.sql.DataSource',
                                 'jbdc/app22','DefaultPrincipalMapping',
                                 'was7CellManager01/db2inst1',""
                               ]
                               [
                                 appname,"",
                                 source+',WEB-INF/web.xml',
                                 'jdbc/app1db','javax.sql.DataSource',
                                 'jbdc/app22','DefaultPrincipalMapping',
                                 'was7CellManager01/db2inst1',""
                               ]
                             ] 
         ]

AdminApp.install(source, attrs)
```

Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Isn't there is a missing coma between both of your MapResRefToEJB values ? (line 27)

Comment: you are right, thanks a lot. I was confused with (line 14) in the error...

Comment: If the answer is correct, could you accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing coma between both of your MapResRefToEJB values @ line 27.